# Perl multidimensional array question

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a program that prints out the location of commas in a paragraph of text in the form

For example if the paragraph is

```
one,two,three
three and a half
four,five
six
seven,eight
```

The program will print

```
0:4
0:8
2:5
4:6
```

I would like to use this output to create an array where the numbers after the colon are listed across columns in the row specified by the index before the colon. The array formed by the coordinates above would be

```
4 8
<blank or character '.'>
5
<blank or character '.'>
6
```

so array[0,0] = 4, array[0,1] = 8
array[1,0] = empty
array[2,0] = 5
etc...

I bet this is simple but I need help to write it.

```
$data_file="file.out"; 
open(DAT, $data_file) || die("Could not open file!"); 
@raw_data=<DAT>; 
close(DAT);

my %array;

my $line = 0;

foreach $newline(@raw_data) {
    chomp;

while ( $newline=~m/(,|;|:|and)/) {
            push @{ $array{$line} }, pos($newline);  # autovivification
}

    $line++; }
```

Comment: sorry the array output didn't print properly

Comment: This seems like an odd request... what's the final desired outcome? What will you be using the arrays for?

Comment: row 0: 4 8   row 1: blank     row 2: 5    row 3: blank   row 4: 6

Comment: /row 0: 4 8 / row 1: blank / row 2: 5 / row 3: blank / row 4: 6

Comment: to extract elements from the paragraph separated by the commas and other delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %array;

my $line = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    while ( /(,|;|:|(?:and))/g ) {
        my $position = pos() - length($1) + 1;
        push @{ $array{$line} }, $position;  # autovivification
    }

    $line++;
}

for ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %array ) {
    my $flattened_value = join ', ', @{ $array{$_} };
    print "$_ -> $flattened_value\n";
}

__DATA__
one,two,three
three and a half
four,five
six
seven,eight
```

### Output

```
0 -> 4, 8
1 -> 7
2 -> 5
4 -> 6
```

Refer: [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html), [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html), [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Refer the following documents to get an understanding of Perl's data structures and especially **autovivification** which has been used in this example.

- [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: racket99: You are welcome. You can accept an answer by clicking the *tick* mark next to the answer.

Comment: question: how do i sort this.  the $VAR1 variable in the program prints out in row order '4','0','2'.  Is there a way I can have it print in order '0','2','4'?  Thanks

Comment: racket99: Considering that you are new to Perl, remember to read all those documentation. :-)

Comment: Alan, I modified your code (see my original post) as I need to specify several delimiters to modify and my data is in an external file. Not surprisingly after my edits it stopped working.  Wondering if there is anything obvious I left out?  Your original code didn't work since I needed to check for the delimiter 'and' and 'with' which wasn't being picked up.